# how to convert an odd number length hexadecimal of an image to base64

Tags: python, base64, hex

I have images stored in hexadecimal strings some of which are odd length strings. I need to convert these into base64 for upload to Clarifai's API which takes base64 images as input. These strings are very long, over 30k in characters. The even length strings work fine but I can't figure out how to deal with odd number length strings.

I tried the following snippet to convert the odd strings to even by padding them with a 0 at the beginning, however, these strings aren't working either.

```
    lab = row['concept_name']
    img_hex = row['image_byte']
    if len(img_hex) % 2 != 1:
        img_from_hex = bytes.fromhex(img_hex.replace('0x', ''))   
     else:
        img_from_hex = bytes.fromhex(img_hex.replace('0x','0'))
```

When I just try to plan convert the image without padding I get this error

```
ValueError: non-hexadecimal number found in fromhex() arg at position 32757
```

[A sample file can be found here](https://solutions-demos-data.s3.amazonaws.com/hex_output.txt)

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Not sure what the solution is but you don't want to pad a `0` at the start, the first bytes `FFD8FF` are significant and mark the image as a jpg

Comment: That's a great point. Is there a specific point in the string I should pad, maybe 0 at the end

Comment: Worth a try, better than the beginning. Do you know how these "hex" strings were created? If you have access to that code maybe we can find the bug

Comment: No i don't have acess to that code. It was given to me by a client who doesn't have the person who encoded these original hex codes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For posterity, the odd length hex strings (for images) need to be even numbers in length. If they are not you will have a really bad time. You could try stripping the 0x at the beginning and then padding 0 at the beginning or end to see if that works. If it doesn't then it means that there is lost data or corruption in the string. Unless you know where exactly the corruption,there isn't really much you can do